# Splitting row-values into multiple rows in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have an R data frame as follows-

```
df <- data.frame(
   FDR =  c (0.009, 0.007, 0.007), 
   Probe_ID =  c("1555272_at", "1557203_at", "1557384_at"),
   Gene.Symbol =  c("RSPH10B2///RSPH10B","PABPC1L2B///PABPC1L2A","LOC100506639///ZNF131"),
   Gene.ID = c("728194///222967","645974///340529","100506639///7690"))

df
    FDR   Probe_ID           Gene.Symbol          Gene.ID
1 0.009 1555272_at    RSPH10B2///RSPH10B  728194///222967
2 0.007 1557203_at PABPC1L2B///PABPC1L2A  645974///340529
3 0.007 1557384_at LOC100506639///ZNF131 100506639///7690
```

I want to split the data frame based on row-values of column `df$Gene.symbol`, based on pattern `///`. The resulted data frame should look like -

```
FDR     Probe_ID    Gene.symbol     Gene.ID 
0.009   15111_at    RSPH10B2        728194 
0.009   15111_at    RSPH10B         222967 
0.007   15222_at    PABPC1L2B       645974 
0.007   15222_at    PABPC1L2A       340529 
0.007   15333_at    LOC100506639    100506639 
0.007   15333_at    ZNF131          7690
```

I have tried the following code but it didn't work and produced columns with repetitive elements-

```
s <- strsplit(gsub("///","",df$Gene.symbol),", ",fixed = TRUE)
res <- data.frame(Id = rep(df$Gene.symbol, lengths(s)), result = unlist(s))
ans <- merge(annotated,res)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `gsub("\\/\\/\\/","",df$Gene.Symbol)` beacuse `/` is a special character is important to add `\\` before any special character in `gsub`or `regex`. See `?regex` in R-console for more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  separate_rows(Gene.Symbol, Gene.ID, sep = "///")

# A tibble: 6 x 4
    FDR Probe_ID   Gene.Symbol  Gene.ID  
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>        <chr>    
1 0.009 1555272_at RSPH10B2     728194   
2 0.009 1555272_at RSPH10B      222967   
3 0.007 1557203_at PABPC1L2B    645974   
4 0.007 1557203_at PABPC1L2A    340529   
5 0.007 1557384_at LOC100506639 100506639
6 0.007 1557384_at ZNF131       7690
```

Comment: `separate_rows` is now part of `tidyr` not `dplyr` but otherwise works the same way

Answer (score 0):

Using `strsplit` with `by`.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, by(df, df$Probe_ID, function(x) {
  cbind(`rownames<-`(x[,1:2], NULL), sapply(x[,-(1:2)], strsplit, "///"))
}))
res
#                FDR   Probe_ID  Gene.Symbol   Gene.ID
# 1555272_at.1 0.009 1555272_at     RSPH10B2    728194
# 1555272_at.2 0.009 1555272_at      RSPH10B    222967
# 1557203_at.1 0.007 1557203_at    PABPC1L2B    645974
# 1557203_at.2 0.007 1557203_at    PABPC1L2A    340529
# 1557384_at.1 0.007 1557384_at LOC100506639 100506639
# 1557384_at.2 0.007 1557384_at       ZNF131      7690
```

*Note:* If you get `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-character argument`, your variables may contain `factors`. You may want to do `df[2:4] <- lapply(df[2:4], as.character)` and update your R version soon.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(FDR = c(0.009, 0.007, 0.007), Probe_ID = c("1555272_at", 
"1557203_at", "1557384_at"), Gene.Symbol = c("RSPH10B2///RSPH10B", 
"PABPC1L2B///PABPC1L2A", "LOC100506639///ZNF131"), Gene.ID = c("728194///222967", 
"645974///340529", "100506639///7690")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```